# Understanding currying by example

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I was reading about curried function somewhere, which sounded confusing. The example confused me even further. Lets say I have a function:

```
power :: (Int, Float) -> Float -- computes the nth power of b
power (n, b) =
    if n == 0 then 1.0 else b * power (n-1, b)
```

Now I define another function `powerc:: Int -> Float -> Float` such that

```
powerc n b =
    if n == 0 then 1.0 else b * powerc (n-1) b
```

Can someone please explain to me how is `powerc` a curried version of `power` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `powerc` allows partial application now:

```
square = powerc 2
```

BTW,

```
powerc = curry power
```

Comment: How can we directly write square = powerc 2

Comment: What is the value of b and n in that case ?

Comment: `square = powerc 2` defines a new function `square :: Float -> Float`.  Intuitively, it's a version of `powerc` in which `n` is always 2.  `b` will be whatever you pass to it; i.e. `square 4 == 16.0`.

Comment: The value of `n` is `2` as you have provided a value for this argument. Because `powerc` is a 2-ary function, the partial application `powerc 2` is an unary function. That is, you can apply `square` to an argument, which becomes the second argument of `powerc`.

Comment: see [partial application](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_application), you can rewrite that statement as: `square b = powerc 2 b` or `square = \b → powerc 2 b`.

Answer (score 5):

The former is a function taking an `Int, Float` tuple, while the latter is essentially a chain of functions each taking a *single* argument and returning a function taking the next.

That is, `powerc` takes an `Int` and returns a *function* that takes a `Float` and returns a `Float`.

You could make use of this with partial application. For example `square = powerc 2` or `cube = powerc 3` which are each then simple `Float -> Float` functions with the value for `n` captured.

Non-curried functions don't afford this easy partial application. It's nice to use partial application when the leading arguments are a kind of one-time configuration of the function's behavior. It also becomes particularly useful when trying to reshape functions to be passed to higher-order functions. For example, you could map `powerc 2` (without defining) over a list to square them all.

Hope that helps!